# duplicates entries are entered into my SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am getting confused in my SQL Server data. I have a table with these columns

```
userid int identity(1,1) primary key
username varchar(50)
password varchar(50)
emailid varchar(50)
registerdate datetime
```

Now one user enters his details from my asp.net page and register himself on my website

As you see I add primary key and identity increment of one in my table. But when user enter his detail he registered two times

When I check my database I get this detail

```
userid  username password emailid         registerdate
125      akash    abcd    abc@gmail.com   2014-01-24 19:40:47.000
126      akash    abcd    abc@gmail.com   2014-01-24 19:40:47.000
```

Now check the time here at the same time how can two entries are possible of one user?

I am not getting it. Please tell me why this is happening ?

Thanks

Comment: i think is not on sql server. please check you code on ASP maybe you have code there are sends twice.

Comment: no it not happen with every entry it happens sometime not always i check it @JohnWoo

Comment: try inserting directly in sql server and see if it inserts twice. maybe it happens while the user is inserting the record and it reloads the page causing to send another insert.

Comment: The only scenario that I can think of that would make SQL Server responsible for this behaviour, would be that the table has a TRIGGER on it. However, a TRIGGER would fire every time, unless it was coded in an obscure way.

Comment: no it is not inserting twice. In my sql table data enter continuously sometime there is a queue of records to save in database I think may be traffic  the issue here  @JohnWoo

Comment: If it so hard to debug, then make the username an unique key and see when you get the unique key constraint violation. At that point you should have a better understanding of what happens. (In any case the username field should be a unique key)

Comment: Probably a postback problem or something else in ASP. Add a unique constraint on the username and you will get an error message that shows you when it happens the second time. Apart from that you have a big issue with how you store the passwords - I hope in the real database they are encrypted and not plain Varchars

Comment: yeaah it is encrypted not in plain varchar and one thing there is no postback problem i check it too @Pleun